# Model Constructor return Array

Tags: asp.net, arrays, constructor, model

I am having issues with my model `Contructor`.

```
namespace arkiv.Models
{
    public class BlogPost
    {
    public string string1 { get; set; }

    public BlogPost()
    {
        string[] myArray= new string[2] 
        {   string1
            ,string22
        };
        return myArray;
    }
```

Errormessage : `Since BlogPost.BlogPost() returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression.`

Why can't the Model Constructor return my Array?

Comment: Hello.. you can't return an array in a constructor. The return type of a constructor is void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot return value from constructor in C#. instead of this you can expose that value as property.

```
public class BlogPost
    {
    public string string1 { get; set; }
    public readonly List<string> Myarray {get ;}
    public BlogPost()
    {
        Myarray= new List<string>() 
        {   string1
            ,string22
        };
    }
```